# External application : loop through open windows from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I open a Master Planning and a Resource Pool via Excel, but MSP randomly creates a Project1 including both other files.

I want Excel to check if it exists and close it without saving

```
Dim ProjApps As new Collection
Dim ProjApp As MSProject.Application
Dim Proj As MSProject.Project

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ProjApp = GetX("MSProject.Application")

ProjApp.Application.AppMaximize
AppActivate ProjApp
SendKeys "{RIGHT}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

If ProjApp.FileOpenEx(files.MSPRessPool, False, , , , , , , , , , 3) Then
    Set Proj = ProjApp.ActiveProject
    ProjApps.Add Proj
Else
    MsgBox "Fichier non trouvé : " & vbCrLf & files.MSPRessPool
    Exit Sub
End If

If ProjApp.FileOpenEx(files.MasterPlanning, False, , , , , , , , , , 3) Then
    Set Proj = ProjApp.ActiveProject
    ProjApps.Add Proj
Else
    MsgBox "Fichier non trouvé : " & vbCrLf & files.MSPRessPool
    Exit Sub
End If

For each Proj in ProjApps
    Debug.Print Proj.Name
    If Proj.Name = "Project1" then
        Proj.Application.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave
    End If
Next
```

The Project1 file doesn't appear in the ProjApps collection so that I can not close it

How can check for open MSP files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that specific application.  Your errors are specific to class properties.  You're not getting a property doesn't exist error so my first line of thinking if that projapp isn't what you expect it to be.  Have you stepped through your code with F8, inspected the properties with local, set a watch on proj anf projapp, and used the immediate window to identify the object you grabbed? also, use f2 and make sure the object supports those properties... you might have to use .index(1) or .item or some other construct

Comment: I agree with you. It seems like I need to create a collection that will be looped through via the for loop (I'm not familiar with collections)
So i added `Dim ProjApps As New Collection` but I can only populate it with Proj items when I created them. I debugged by adding `Debug.Print Proj.Name` in the `For Each proj in ProjApps` loop and only get Master Planning and Resource Pool while Project1 has been created by MSP

Comment: just my two cents here... i vastly prefer dictionaries over collections.  but as many have pointed out, i am profoundly oblivious.

Comment: I am not familiar with dictionaries either. I only read here and ther that `For Each` loops rely on Collections so I tried that. Couldn't think it is so difficult to look for open file in other applications

Comment: i definitely recommend trying dictionaries. they are better then collections in almost every way.  for example, you can extract an array of keys or query to see if a specific key exists, this means you can check for duplicates without having to handle an error like you would with collections. another example, a key doesn't have to be s string, it can be any data type except an array.... yes, a key can be an object! and of course the item can be any data type including array.

Comment: for each is pretty awesome but you're not limited to collections.  ahem (cough) dictionaries (cough) but that's actually not my point this time.... look into enumerators.  you can create your own enumerator and step through those with a for each.  added benefit, the auto word complete works.  very handy for getting rid of pesky magic numbers and making strongly typed code. [this site is a good start](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MS Project object model has a [Projects object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/projects-object-project) which is a collection of open projects so you don't need to create your own.

```
For Each Proj In ProjApp.Projects
    Debug.Print Proj.Name
    If Proj.Name = "Project1" Then
        Proj.Application.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rachel Hettinger's answer, this piece of code runs fine:

```
    For Each Proj In ProjApp.Projects
       Proj.Activate
       If Proj.Name = "Project1" Then
         Proj.Application.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave
         Exit For
       End If
    Next
```

This one works also

```
    For ProjNum = 1 To Projects.Count
       Projects(ProjNum).Activate
       If Projects(ProjNum).Name = "Project1" Then
          Proj.Application.FileCloseEx pjDoNotSave
          Exit For
       End If
    Next ProjNum
```